# How to find out if an AWS VPC Subnet is a "public subnet"?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I want to find out if a given AWS VPC subnet is a ["public subnet"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html) i.e. if it has direct access to the internet. As I understand it, for this I need to check if the route table associated with that subnet is associated with an internet gateway i.e. it has an entry with `"destination_cidr_block"="0.0.0.0/0"` and `"gateway_id"="igw-blahblah"`. So using the Ruby AWS SDK, I am doing something like this:

```
def is_public_subnet(subnet_id)
    client = AWS::EC2::Client.new
    rt = client.describe_route_tables(:filters => [:name => "association.subnet-id", :values => [subnet_id]])
    if rt[:route_table_set].empty?
        # no route table associated with it. Must be using main route table.
        rt = client.describe_route_tables(:filters => [:name => "association.main", :values => ["true"]])
    end
    rt[:route_table_set][0][:route_set].each do |route|
        if route[:destination_cidr_block] == "0.0.0.0/0"
            if route[:gateway_id].start_with?("igw-")
                return true
            end
         end
    end
    return false
end
```

I want to ask if there is a better way to do this both in terms of the approach and the ruby sdk code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for the ruby code, but the approach is valid: a subnet is public if it routes to an internet gateway and it's instances will be reachable if they are attached to an Elastic IP.